# Android, Trying to read through a file stored online. But file doesn't have a type tag

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I am trying to read through a file stored online, but the file doesn't have a type tag. What's up with my code, and what do I need to change?

Code:

```
public void Button1Click (View view) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  { 
    int countWords = 0;
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("http://textfile/textfile");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    }
    in.close();
}
```

When I run the code, it says "Unfortunately, Test has stopped"

Comment: If it says "Unfortunately Test has stopped," you should have an error message in your LogCat that give you more information on why it stopped. Have you checked that?

Comment: Is `"http://textfile/textfile"``your actual file URL? Have you tried typing this URL into your browser?

Comment: Yes, its the actual file url, and it is a text document file. But it just doesn't say .txt at the end of the file

Comment: but textfile isnt a domain so this can't be a valid url